# preg_match coordinates with degree sign

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to capture the coordinates of an input that could look like this

> 22°50'23.46"S,  43° 0'44.80"W

or this

> 41°12'27.84"N, 16°18'40.15"E

I think the problem is the degree symbols in my pattern. My current code:

```
$found = preg_match("~(\d+\p{Sm}\d+\s*\'\s*\d+\s*\.\s*\d+\s*\"\s*[N|S])\s*,\s*(\d+\s*\p{Sm}\s*\d+\s*\'\s*\d+\s*\.\s*\d+\s*\"\s*[E|W])~i", $_POST['submission']['url'], $matches);
```

$matches stays empty.

Comment: Instead of `\p{Sm}` try `\xB0`.

Comment: The degree sign is in category `\p{So}` (Symbol, Other), not `\p{Sm}` (Symbol, Math).  Also, you have to add the `/u` modifier to activate the Unicode category escapes (e.g., `"~\p{So}~u"`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you should try ignoring the actual degrees and tick marks and focus just on the data you want to grab.

```
(\d+)\D+(\d+)\D+(\d+)\.(\d+)\W(\w+)\W+(\d+)\D+(\d+)\D+(\d+)\.(\d+)\W(\w)
```

This regex should capture the following data:

```
41
12
27
84
N
16
18
40
15
E
```

(Edit2: Corrected to properly pick up the N without punctuation.)

Comment: just put the full answer please.

Comment: This *is* a full answer.  That's a regex and the result.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `/u` modifier to make the engine interpret the pattern as Unicode.

Answer (score 1):

What is stopping you from using the `°` character literally?

```
/
  (\d+\s*°\s*  \d+\s*'\s*  \d+\s*\.\s*\d+\s*"\s*  [NS])
  \s*,\s*
  (\d+\s*°\s*  \d+\s*'\s*  \d+\s*\.\s*\d+\s*"\s*  [EW])
/xi
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `mb_ereg_match` instead to support UTF-8 chars. Docs: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php

Initialize mb* like this:

> ```
> mb_regex_encoding('UTF-8');
> mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
> ```

Comment: This is a non-default extension. Can't it be done with a simple preg_match?

Comment: No, no it isn't.  `mbstring` is meant for character encoding trickery, and *downgrading* to slower, less useful POSIX regexes is silly.  The default PCRE extension [includes comprehensive Unicode character support](http://us.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php).