# Having trouble with a preg_match_all and a degree symbol

Tags: php, regex

I am having trouble with a preg_match_all on a string that contains a degree symbol.  The sample of code is below.

```
//Sample data
$x = "<array_0>
        <id>text-21650</id>
        <text>Lat/Long 38° 57' 34 N,  106° 21' 38 W</text>
      </array_0>";

$reels = '/<(\w+)\s*([^\/>]*)\s*(?:\/>|>(.*)<\/\s*\\1\s*>)/s';

preg_match_all($reels, $x, $elements);

foreach ($elements[1] as $ie => $xx) {
  $name = $elements[1][$ie];
  $cdend = strpos($elements[3][$ie], "<");
  if ($cdend > 0) {
    $xmlary[$name] = substr($elements[3][$ie], 0, $cdend - 1);
  }

  if (preg_match($reels, $elements[3][$ie]))
    $xmlary[$name] = processEl($elements[3][$ie]);
  else if ($elements[3][$ie] !== null) {
    $xmlary[$name] = $elements[3][$ie];
  }
}
```

For some reason it doesn't work properly with the degree symbols in there.  If I take it out it works. I would really like to find a way that they can stay in there without changing them.  I am also wondering if there may be other extended character that could cause a problem too.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: "For some reason it doesn't work properly" --> what does that mean? What is the intended behavior and the actual output?

Comment: Free piece of advice... use an XML parser, not regular expressions for parsing XML.

Comment: possible duplicate of [preg_match coordinates with degree sign](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5355874/preg-match-coordinates-with-degree-sign)

Comment: That regex matches your sample string just fine when I try it.  Show us some code we can actually run that displays the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [this previous answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5355874/preg-match-coordinates-with-degree-sign).

Basically you will have to switch to Unicode matching.

> Use mb_ereg_match instead to support UTF-8 chars. Docs:
>   http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php
>
> Initialize mb* like this:
>
> mb_regex_encoding('UTF-8'); mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, and [this other post from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3140734/unicode-preg-replace-problem-in-php) helped me. Basically, to look for a degree symbol, you'd use \x{00B0}, ie.

> preg_match_all("/\x{00B0}/", $x, $elements);